# Excel form using DTPicker2 control is broken on single machine after moving to Win10

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file that contains VBA code and user forms.

One machine has been migrated to Windows 10. The Excel major version hasn't changed though (16). One of the forms lost almost all the controls on it and the user is getting

> Compile error: Method or data member not found

at the line `Me.cmbWeek.ListCount`.

It looks as if this control is not existent in the file on that machine. I wouldn't say it is Windows10 incompatibility as some other machines migrated to Windows 10 flawlessly.

How can I debug what's wrong? The file has worked for years on several machines including the machine of this user (until on Win10). Checked references and there's nothing missing.

The form on user's machine (broken).
[image: broken form]

The form on on all other users' machines (proper).
[image: form working correctly]

I cross-posted to other forums:

[excelforum.com](https://www.excelforum.com/exc%E2%80%A6fter-moving-to-win10.html)

[mrexcel.com](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/%E2%80%A6n10.1140327/#post-5523069)

[ozgrid.com](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/1227929-form-is-broken-on-single-machine-after-moving-to-win10/&postID=1237584#post1237587)

We managed to trace the problem to the DTPicker2 control on the form. It is part of MSCOMCT2.OCX library. It is present on user's machine, the same as on mine. That machine is version SP4 of the file whereas all other machines have SP6.

I can see that Excel reference points to some other destination than C:\Windows\SYSWOW64 - it points to other app's install path. Probably other app changed something in the registry.

When trying to uncheck the SP4 reference and load SP6 reference I get error

> "Can't change references, in use".

Reinstalling office and registering MSCOMCT2.OCX did not help. As it's only two controls causing the issue - or so it seems - I'm now into replacing them with other date picker controls if there are any. If not, I might even use plain textboxes, though it wouldn't be very good solution. Are there any other controls that could handle calendar?

Comment: Repair the office installation?

Comment: We already update excel from 1803 to 1908 on the machine but it didn't solve the issue. I'm not sure, but I think it's more-less tantamount to repairing, isn't it?

Comment: Is it the same shared instance of the file for all machines, or does each one has its own copy?

Comment: It's shared file but all users make their own copy of it as 'installation'.. It doesn't matter whether the user opens his own copy or the shared one, same result. Of course all other users open the share file without issue (the form works normally)

Comment: On the affected computer, what happens if you create an empty file, add a userform in it and place tabs and comboboxes on it in the designer?

Comment: We managed to trace the problem is caused by DTPicker2 control on the form.. It's part of MSCOMCT2.OCX library. I checked and it is present on user's machine, the same as on mine. I checked on that machine is ver SP4 of the file whereas all other machines have SP6.. I can see that excel reference points to some other destination than C:\Windows\SYSWOW64 - it points to other app's install path. Probably other app changed something in the registry. When trying to uncheck the SP4 reference and load SP6 reference I'm getting error "Can't change references, in use"..  We're reinstalling the office

Comment: Are you using Office x64? That is [not going to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58318884/what-is-in-use-by-mscomct2-ocx-common-controls-2-6-0#comment102999012_58318884).

Comment: No, it's 64-bit operation system running 32-bit office. Honestly speaking I'm thinking about ditching DTPicker2 all over as the problem seems to be exclusively related to that control. For now, though, as there is still some time to play with it, I would try to make the control working. I also might end up using some other date picker control I happen to come across..

Comment: Then you should probably run regsvr32 on MSCOMCT2.OCX again, making sure it's done under administrator.

Comment: Unfortunately, reinstalling office and registering MSCOMCT2.OCX did not help. As it's only 2 controls causing the issue - or so it seems - I'm now into replacing them with other date picker controls if there are any. If not, I might even use plain textboxes, though it wouldn't be very good solution.. Are there any other controls that could handle calendar?

Answer (score -2):

Do check if the region settings on the PC with Win10 the same as on the older PC's.

Changes in date formats, dots vs comma's, etc. can hugely impact VBA's ability to tinker company processes together.